# Are 2 Django URLs pointing at 1 view unorthodox?

Tags: python, django

I'm in the process of writing a private messaging system and I have 2 URLs which go to the same view (is that bad?). The logic behind this madness relates to the way user relationships are structured in our system...

> ```
>      T
>     / \___
>    C1      \
>    |        C2
>    P1      /  \  
>           P2   P3
> ```

T = Trainer, C = Coach, P = Participant.

We define this structure in a pretty simple way:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    higher_up = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    # ...
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPES, default='P')
```

And bam, We've got a DAG. Here's my 2 urls in `urls.py`:

```
# talk to lower_down
url(r'^pm/(?P<userprofile_pk>\d+)/$', 'private_message'),

# talk to higher_up
url(r'^pm/$', 'private_message'),
```

and the `private_message` view...

```
def private_message(request, userprofile_pk=''):
    me = request.user.userprofile
    src_pk = me.pk

    if userprofile_pk == '': # /pm/
        you = me.higher_up
        dest_pk = you.pk
    else: # userprofile_pk was not blank /pm/<num>
        you = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=userprofile_pk) 
        dest_pk = you.pk

    # Are they allowed to talk?
    if me.is_assoc_with(you):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    feed_vars = {
        'dest_pk': dest_pk,
        'src_pk' : src_pk,
    }

    return render(request, 'talk/private_message.html', feed_vars)
```

The `me.is_assoc_with(you)` bit just checks where `me` and `you` are in the userprofile structure. In the above ASCII art diagram, P1 should not be allowed to talk with P2. T can talk to C1, C1 and C2 cannot talk. T and P3 can talk, etc.

Is this an ok pattern to have 2 URLs go to 1 view that handles logic based on the URL?

I do feel like I am reinventing the wheel here. I think there should be a more flexible approach with settings for who can talk to whom factored out of the business logic itself.

Answer (score 1):

Why not separate the view functions?

```
# talk to lower_down
url(r'^pm/(?P<userprofile_pk>\d+)/$', 'private_message_down'),

# talk to higher_up
url(r'^pm/$', 'private_message_up'),
```

The view functions:

```
def private_message(src, dest):
    # Are they allowed to talk?
    if src.is_assoc_with(dest):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    feed_vars = {
        'dest_pk': dest.pk,
        'src_pk' : src.pk,
    }

    return render(request, 'talk/private_message.html', feed_vars)

def private_message_down(request, userprofile_pk):
    src = request.user.userprofile

    # TODO: profile actually exists?
    dest = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=userprofile_pk) 

    return private_message(src, dest)

def private_message_up(request):
    src = request.user.userprofile
    dest = me.higher_up

    return private_message(src, dest)
```

I added a TODO for failure handling, I think you should wrap the `.get` lookup in a `try-except UserProfile.DoesNotExist`, for example:

```
from django.http import Http404


def private_message_down(request, userprofile_pk):
    src = request.user.userprofile

    try:
        dest = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=userprofile_pk) 
    catch UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return private_message(src, dest)
```

Also, you probably want to decorate `private_message_*` with `@login_required` (`from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required`).